# Language/file format for circuit-diagram description

Tags: embedded, circuit-design, diagram, basic-language

Is there any language/file format that can describe the block circuit diagram?
For example, the following circuit diagram [image]

might be represented by something like:

A {
  P00: VDD,
  P01,
  P02: GND,
  P10: GPIO output B.P00
  P11: GPIO input B.P01
  P12: GPIO output R0
}

B {
  P00: GPIO input A.P10,
  P01: GPIO output A.P11,
  P10,
  P11,
}

R0 (A.P12, LED0)

LED0 {
  +: R0,
  -: GND
}

Comment: Do you know SPICE? Or some HDL (hardware description language)

Comment: Are you talking about a netlist?

Comment: EDIF was one, quite widely used

Comment: Hi, I know a little about netlist. AFAIK, it can describe the circuit in electronic-component level. However, I was wondering if there is something similar in chip level. For example, if A is a 8051 chip.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of, there is a language called [VHDL-AMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL-AMS) and there is also spice. SPICE is good for simulation, VHDL-AMS is not widely used but is intended for hardware. Almost every software that uses a graphical approach with block diagrams or graphical symbols is a proprietary format (all of the spice packages have there own file format, all of the HDL compilers have their specific graphical format).